# Custom grouping with MUI Autocomplete in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a custom grouping with MUI Autocomplete component but no result.
Seems like the library itself doesn't provide a solution (I wish I was wrong).

[image]

The above grouping is pretty easy with `groupBy` property.
The second one - I have already spent a whole day , but couldn't find a solution.

I have tried to add custom options and changed dropdown box styles in order to somehow achieve the goal, but internally Autocomplete filters the options by the return value of the `getOptionLabel` or filters with some internal function.

If I use `filterOptions` prop to not include the unwanted options in the filtering process, it just removes them completely.

Maybe I am just trying to implement a thing out of the box which is not available for this Service.

P.S. Both of the groupings should be always visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paper Component, as there is no need of using groupBy, for showing the last element, that is, `Enter address manually`. I had to develop the same functionality, and was able to get the results with MuiAutocomplete's `paperComponent`

https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-paper-in-autocomplete-nhbp7?file=/demo.js

Screenshot of my work
[Autocomplete element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKSLJ.png)
[Component for Paper Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xkoz.png)

Comment: can you add code instead of screenshots? this enables the OP to quickly copy code and adjust it to their needs